# PyQT5 QSystemTrayIcon activated signal not working

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qsystemtrayicon

I am trying to print a text when system tray icon is clicked in PyQT5 program. I tried to connect PyQT5 QSystemTrayIcon activated signal (emitted when system tray icon is clicked) to custom method, but the method is not called.
Here is simple example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSystemTrayIcon, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot


@pyqtSlot()
def action(signal):
    print('test1')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
icon = QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon('any_icon.png'), app)
icon.show()

icon.activated.connect(action)
#icon.activated['QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason'].connect(action)
#icon.pyqtConfigure(activated=action)

print(icon.receivers(icon.activated))  # to check if is connected
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In example are 3 ways of connecting the signal to slot (two of them commented). I tried both using method with and without decorator @pyqtSlot(). Connection raises no errors. Even the print of signal receivers says it is connected to 1 slot. However, it does nothing when systray icon is clicked.

**The question:** Is the signal connection incorrect, or is the signal not emitted at all?

*System: Ubuntu 16.04, PyQT5.8. However, should be working on others systems too as PyQT is multiplatform-ish.
PS: I have read [official PyQT5 signal/slot documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html) and many related questions on stack overflow, but had not found the same issue. The closest one I think may relate [is in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053244/qt-qsystemtrayicon-not-sending-activated-signal), but not applicable to python.
Any tips would be really appreciated. Thank you very much!
Edit: fixed typos in text*

Comment: I have tried it and it works well. I'm using Arch Linux, PyQt5.8, Qt5.8 and gnome as desktop manager.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you for trying it out and detailed info. I forgot to mention that I have _Ubuntu_ with _Unity_,
not _Gnome_, so that led me to some testing and I think that there is a bug in _PyQT_ on _Unity_. More info in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @Murdo and @eyllanesc answers, I tested the sample code on multiple systems.
Clean install only with Python 3.5 and `pip3 install pyqt5`. System tray icon activated signal is:

Not working:

- *Ubuntu 16.04 - Unity, PyQt 5.8 and PyQt 5.5.1*
- *Ubuntu 16.10 - Unity, PyQt 5.8 and PyQt 5.7*

Working:

- *Ubuntu 16.04 - Gnome, PyQt 5.8*
- *Arch Linux - Gnome, PyQt 5.8*
- *Kubuntu 16.10, KDE, PyQt 5.7*
- *Xubuntu - Openbox with Stalonetray*

It seems like the sample code is correct and there is a **bug in *QT* using *Unity*** - `QSystemTrayIcon` does not send `activated` signal when the system tray icon is clicked. *[Bug report link](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55911).*

**SOLUTION** `QSystemTrayIcon` activation (clicked) signal can be bypassed by assigning a `QMenu` to the system tray icon and detecting `QMenu().aboutToShow` signal instead. This way when the tray icon is clicked, signal `aboutToShow` is sent, then menu displayed. It is not exactly the same result, but there seems to be no other way of detecting system tray icon activation on *Unity*. Thanks to @Murdo for an idea. Simple code example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QSystemTrayIcon, QMenu
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


def action():
    print('System tray icon clicked.')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
icon = QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon('any_icon.png'), parent=app)
icon.show()

menu = QMenu(parent=None)
menu.aboutToShow.connect(action)
icon.setContextMenu(menu)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem with PyQt 5.9 and Lubuntu 16.04

Comment: This is the only workaround I am aware of, but sadly it is unable to differ left/right clicks. Try to test different methods and the documentation - maybe you will find a solution. If you do, please share here with others. Good luck

Answer (score 3):

Your example  works just fine in Xubuntu under openbox with stalonetray.
However in Xubuntu proper it did not work ! 
But when I added something like:

```
mNu =  QMenu() 
test =  QAction('Test',mNu)
test.triggered.connect(action)
icon.setContextMenu(mNu)
```

it worked in xubuntu. I seems that somehow Ubuntu only expects to show a menu in the tray thing.

Comment: The problem is I need to call the `action()` when systray icon is clicked, but
the example above sends signal when the menu item is clicked. However, the fact it works on _Xubuntu_
helped me with testing and you gave me an idea how to
bypass the problem using `QMenu()` - more in my currently added answer. Thank you very much!